# In iOS set product name ,app id and code signing identity during build

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, automation

I want to set the iOS app 'product name' & 'appId' & 'code signing identity' during build time . I am building 2 app with same code base but 'product name', 'appId' & 'code signing identity' is different .  I am manually changing the 'product name', 'appId' & 'code signing identity' for each build . I want to set a parameter in code , and according to that corresponding 'product name', 'appId' & 'code signing identity' should be changed during build time. Can anybody help me on this.

Comment: Create separate targets as suggested by @spassas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set anything during build time, you just have to create 2 different build targets. You can find a related tutorial at http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/building-flockwork-creating-targets-for-free-and-full-versions-in-a-single-xcode-project/